# Split string from execute result

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2014

I have result when executing my query like that:

```
+--------+--------+
-  col1  -  col2  -
+--------+--------+
-  a,b   -   1    -
-  a,c   -   2    -
-  b,c   -   3    -
- a,b,c  -   4    -
- a,c,d  -   5    -
+--------+--------+
```

How I can split each result row into new row result with only "a" or "b" or "c"

```
+--------+--------+
-  col1  -  col2  -
+--------+--------+
-  a     -   1    -
-  a     -   2    -
-  a     -   4    -
-  a     -   5    -
-  b     -   1    -
-  b     -   3    -
-  b     -   4    -
-  c     -   2    -
-  c     -   3    -
-  c     -   4    -
-  c     -   5    -
-  d     -   5    -
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I fogot, I have SQL server 2014 R2.

Comment: search for string split function like `Jeff Moden's` `DelimitedSplit8k` and use that

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select s.value, t.col2
from t cross apply
     string_split(col1, ',') s
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's work with SQL Server 20'16.